# How to add object to react-final-form field name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-final-form, final-form

This react-final-form component will return the following result

```
<Field
   name="answers[0].name"
   component="input"
   type="radio"
   value="0"
/>


{ answers: [ { name: 'value' } ] }
```

How to add another property? that will end like This

```
{ answers: [ { name: 'user input value will here', other: 'my custom data' } ] }
```

According to final-form you can name your field component in 4 ways
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `initialValues` prop to the form which will pre-populate the result.

```
<Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    initialValues={{
        answers: [ { other: 'your custom data' } ]
    }}
>
    <Field
        name="answers[0].name"
        component="input"
        type="text"
    />
</Form>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible I did that actually but my scenario is `other: 'your custom data'` is a data from previous screen . Like example the previous screen you need to choose radio button options and the result let say `type: 'food"` . I want to insert this `type` to `answer` that will result to `{name: 'value' type: 'food'}`

Comment: Can't you get the data from the previous screen then populate `initialValues` with it?

Comment: I can actually let me try your suggestion.

Comment: anyway, in initial values, it's not `... answers: [ { other: 'your custom data' } ] ...` but `... answers: [ { name: 'your custom data' } ] ...`